# VB.Net create functions under categories

Tags: vb.net

How can i make custom functions that are in the same category in the editor.
For example My.Computer.FileSystem.
Has a lot of functions inside.

I would like to make something like this.

UsefulFunctions.Weather.GetTemp()

UsefulFunctions.Weather.GetInfo()

UsefulFunctions.Weather.GetLala()

so on...

Comment: Assuming `Weather` is a class, you could place that class in the `UsefulFunctions` [namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt9tafza.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the comment about namespaces and the answer of Hadoko.Chen gives you the most useful answer:

```
Namespace UsefulFunctions
    Public Module Weather
        Public Function GetTemp()
            ....
        End Function

        Public Function GetInfo()
            ....
        End Function

        Public Function GetLala()
            ....
        End Function
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Any class or module you put with the `Namespace UsefulFunctions` will be shown in Intellisense when you type `UsefulFunctions.`. They don't need to be on the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with shared methods, so you can use them without instancing them first.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Console.WriteLine(UsefulFunctions.Weather.GetTemp())
        Console.WriteLine(UsefulFunctions.Weather.GetInfo())
        Console.WriteLine(UsefulFunctions.OtherClass.GetSomething())

        Console.ReadKey(True)

    End Sub

End Module

Public Class UsefulFunctions

    Class Weather

        Public Shared Function GetTemp() As Double
            Return 123
        End Function

        Public Shared Function GetInfo() As String
            Return "Nice weather"
        End Function

        Public Shared Function GetLala() As Object
            Return New Object
        End Function

    End Class

    Class OtherClass

        Public Shared Function GetSomething() As String
            Return "This is something"
        End Function

    End Class

End Class
```